Japanese idiom for "very rarely" - equivalent of the English idiom "once in a blue moon"
Is there a Japanese idiom for "very rarely", similar to the English idiom "once in a blue moon"?
Blue moon refers to something that never happens but might have origins in calendrical calculations. Here is the relevant question for the origin of "blue moon" on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange:
What is the origin of the phrase "blue moon"? Any alternate phrase for it?
I have found たぐいまれ (tagui-mare) but I'm not sure if it is an idiom, how common it is, or if it is the only phrase option, etc.

Adjective
たぐいまれ

extremely rare (uncommon)

Wiktionary

There may be an idiom that refers to something rare like blue moon.

Related: Japanese idioms of improbability It's really hard to find an idiom that expresses that something does happen infrequently...

めったに（～）ない is the most idiomatic way to say "very rare". Note that it incorporates a verb, so めったに V しない translates to "V only once in a blue moon".
ごくまれ (na-adjective) is also widely used. ごく (極) is an intensifier only used with adjectives that mean obscurity (small, few, scarce... rather than big, many, rich...) in the modern language.
The word you found たぐいまれ is not simply "extremely rare" but also has "precious" connotation, so たぐいまれな才能 would be like "a golden talent".
I don't think Japanese has a metaphorical way to say "very rare" that can be used with verbs in a sentence. We do have popular figures of speech for something impossible to happen, such as 西から日が昇る or 石に花が咲く, though they are only used in jokes with the following construction:

君が学校に遅刻しない日があったら、西から日が昇る。
If there were a day you didn't come late to school, the sun would rise in the west.


That one was also on that blog post's list on my answer. Maybe OP can choose which one he likes.

I would argue that expressions like 西から日が昇る and 石に花が咲く are more equivalent to "when pigs fly" since it describes something that is impossible, compared to something that could possibly, yet rarely, happen, like a blue moon.

A great answer (as always!), but since "once in a blue moon" is normally used as an adverbial phrase, ごくまれに or ごくまれにしか [negative verb] is generally a better way to translate it than ごくまれ（な）. (That is, in English, we might occasionally say something like "that's a once-in-a-blue-moon occurrence," where this hyphenated version of the phrase is used as an adjective and corresponds to ごくまれな, but it's much more common to say things like "that only happens once in a blue moon" (それはごくまれにしか起きない), "he only sees her once in a blue moon," "I only go there once in a blue moon," etc.

Here is a blog post from someone that seems to be studying for the Kanji Aptitude test. From a collection of writings called the 枕草子 (まくらのそうし). He/she offered dozens of examples of めったにない事, but maybe this one is best:

盲亀浮木, or もうきふぼく, a Rare Occurence

Apparently, this is some type of Buddhist story; an old and blind sea turtle would come up every one hundred years to take a breath of air. What would be the likelihood that the sea turtle would happen to come up and stick its head through a hole in a piece of driftwood that was passing by? Of the entire sea, that one, single hole. It could happen, yes, but it would be a rare occurrence.

EDIT: Here is an example from goo辞典 that uses the phrase adverbially with a 的に suffix. I believe it can also use のように.
However, as to a phrase that is used commonly, I will align with the claim that Japanese does not have one.

I think you're on to something here, but the OP is asking about a phrase that is overwhelmingly used adverbially (and specifically, to modify a verb), as in "that happens only once in a blue moon." 盲亀（の）浮木 is a noun phrase that can't really be used adverbially, and therefore doesn't work as a direct translation of "once in a blue moon." In certain cases, however, it might work very well as part of a loose or indirect translation. Any chance you could edit your answer to show how one could use it that way?

I will agree that it does not help that the phrase is at best used in poetic contexts. I am also making a difference between a phrase like "once in a blue moon" and "when pigs fly"; there are more common phrases for the latter I believe.
